# MSBuild never ends

Tags: c#, msbuild, ant

```
<Target Name="RunWebServer">
<Exec Command='$(WebServer) /port:3811 /path:$(Path)' />        
</Target>
```

The above command actually translates to the one given below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0"\WebDev.WebServer /port:3811 /path:"D:\PROJEKTI\eMedicine\eMedicine\eMedicine"
```

But when I start build.xml

```
D:\PROJEKTI\eMedicine\eMedicine>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MsBuild.exe Build.xml /target:RunWebServer
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.4926
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.4927]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 15.5.2010 14:06:36.
```

the script never ends. How can I run it and then automatically stop it and thereby prepare for next task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out AsyncExec,

http://blog.eleutian.com/2007/03/01/AsyncExecMsBuildTask.aspx

It should resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter it slightly to not wait on the web server to die, like this

```
<Exec Command='start /B $(WebServer) /port:3811 /path:$(Path)' />
```

I'm not sure exactly why you're starting a Web Server as part of the build, but the default behavior is going to be MSBuild waiting for the `WebDev.WebServer.exe` to exit/close.  You can read more about how `START` works [here](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) and [here](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm). It basically kicks it off as a separate process, not one it waits on.

Comment: now i get Invalid switch:  

Build started 15.5.2010 14:45:07.
Project "D:\PROJEKTI\eMedicine\eMedicine\Build.xml" on node 0 (RunWebServer target(s)).
  Invalid switch - "/port:3811".
Done Building Project "D:\PROJEKTI\eMedicine\eMedicine\Build.xml" (RunWebServer target(s)).

Comment: @senzacionale - It might be a quoting error in your paths (due to paces), try this `<Exec Command='start /B &quot;$(WebServer)&quot; /port:3811 /path:&quot;$(Path)&quot;' />`

Comment: After messing around with this for a long time, I discovered that if you do something like `start /B "path\to\exe" /port:1234 /path:"path\to\website"` you'll get an invalid switch error...this is because when you do `start /B` it will interpret the first argument in quotes as the title of the new dos window, so if you change that to `start /B "" "path\to\exe" /port:1234 /path:"path\to\website"` you'll be fine, the first `""` will be interpreted as the window title. You can put a title in there if you want, but you won't see it.